# object destroyed in stack memory

Tags: c++

let's say I have a class called person with constructor of name,age

```
void addPerson(list<person> &list)
{
  person p("Michael", 19);
  list.push_back(p);
}

int main
{
   list<person> list;
   addPerson(list);
   cout<<list.size();
}
```

I know the list's size is going to be 1, but I feel like as p's scope is only in addPerson() method, once the method finishes, p will be destroyed and memory that p holds will be released, which means list in main will lose this element?

Comment: Assuming you are using `std::list`, the value `p` is *copied* to the list on a call to `push_back`.  .The person object in the list is a copy of `p` and not `p` itself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, but the function prototype is void push_back (const value_type& val), isn't it use a reference rather than a copy?

Comment: You are passing the value by reference.  Nothing stops the `push_back` function from copying that value.  If you want proof: `void foo(int &val) { int myVal = val;}`  See that?  The value is copied to myVal.

Comment: @lxdthriller The parameter type is "reference to a list of persons", not "list of references to persons".

Answer (score 1):

Lets go through your `addPerson` function one by one.

```
void addPerson(list<person> &list)
{
  person p("Michael", 19); // creates a person object on the stack
  list.push_back(p); // makes a copy of p and stores that; this copy will be on the heap

  // provided, you have a comparison operator
  if (p == list.back())  // you have two identical instances now
     std::cout << "same person content\n";

  if (&p != &list.back()) // look at the address in memory
     std::cout << "persons are not identical\n";
} // p goes out of scope and is destroyed, the copy in list lives on
```

If run, both cout statements would be printed.
For completeness, let's also look at the main function:

```
int main
{
   list<person> list;
   addPerson(list); // call by reference, the function acts very same instance of the first line
   cout<<list.size();
}
```